# SVG text accessibility

Tags: svg, text, accessibility, screen-readers

I have the following structure

```html
<h2>
  <svg viewBox='-5 -40 100 50'>
    <!-- some filters that get applied on the elements below -->
    
    <clipPath id='c'>
      <text id='t'>Scooby</text>
    </clipPath>
    
    <g clip-path='url(#c)'>
      <rect x='-5' y='-40' width='100%' height='100%'/>
      <path/>
    </g>
    
    <use xlink:href='#t'/>
    <use xlink:href='#t'/>
  </svg>
</h2>
```

How can I ensure the `text` inside the `clipPath` ("Scooby") gets seen by screen readers *and only once*?

I know SVG `text` should be read by screen readers, but *is that the still the case* when it's inside a `clipPath` element? And what about `use` copies of it?

I'm using this structure in order to get some fancy effects (think [stuff like this](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pens/tags/?selected_tag=feturbulence)) on the heading text (and ditch the .jpg image that's currently used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Remove the SVG from your screenreader using `aria-hidden` and define the label for your `h2` using `aria-labelledby`.**

```
<h2 aria-labelledby="t">
  <svg viewBox='-5 -40 100 50' aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- some filters that get applied on the elements below -->

    <clipPath id='c'>
      <text id='t'>Scooby</text>
    </clipPath>

    <g clip-path='url(#c)'>
      <rect x='-5' y='-40' width='100%' height='100%'/>
      <path/>
    </g>

    <use xlink:href='#t'/>
    <use xlink:href='#t'/>
  </svg>
</h2>
```

Comment: @RobertMonfera it does work for me in Chrome, using NVDA

Comment: This is the best/simplest approach for screen readers. The downside is that it doesn't affect copy & paste: some browsers will copy & paste two copies of your text (for the shadow-DOM text elements in the two `<use>` elements), some will get nothing (because they don't treat the shadow copies as real text). The text inside the clipPath is never accessible or selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `aria-hidden` to [suppress](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) screen reading on specific elements, it'll read "Scooby" just once:

```
<h2>
  <svg viewBox='-5 -40 100 50'>
    <!-- some filters that get applied on the elements below -->

    <clipPath id='c'>
      <text id='t'>Scooby</text>
    </clipPath>

    <g clip-path='url(#c)'>
      <rect x='-5' y='-40' width='100%' height='100%'/>
      <path/>
    </g>

    <use aria-hidden="true" xlink:href='#t'/>
    <use aria-hidden="true" xlink:href='#t'/>
  </svg>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `aria-label` attribute is intended for use when text is not visible on screen

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

```
<h2 aria-label="Scooby">
  <svg> ... </svg>
<h2>
```

or alternatively, I believe most screen readers will use the `<title>` SVG element.

```
<h2>
  <svg>
    <title>Scooby logo</title>
    ...
  </svg>
<h2>
```

You also have the option of using other ARIA attributes, such as `aria-labelledby`.

Comment: <title> (or <desc>) is solid general advice, though your code snippet would still need `aria-hidden` as in my answer